# In Excel, how to check if three values are present on the same line

Tags: excel

In Excel, I am doing a planning with different shifts for all the employees, one line per day.

I'd like to have, as a last column, a "check shift", that will be a cell saying OK if there's the three shifts we have.

For example, for a particular day, we'll have 5 people working, one will be morning, 3 will be mid-day, one will be night
If we have the three values (morning, mid-day, night) on the line, then the check cell will mark OK. Otherwise, KO.

Any clue ?

Comment: Just put a value 1 if the person is present, and 0 if he isn't. In the last column, take the sum of the values and verify if it is larger or equal than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on data in A2:J2, in K2:

`=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(A2:J2,{"morning","mid-day","night"})),"OK","KO")`

Copy down to give similar results for row 3, row 4, etc.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

So if A1 is morning, A2 is mid day, and A3 is night
Put this in D1:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1);ISNUMBER(B1);ISNUMBER(C1));"OK";"KO")
```

You have to put numeric in to get the OK.

You could also do a sum check to see that all the slots have been filled by the total of employees - i.e. add an additional check for the sum the employees to equal 5 or whatever..